# How to solve $ \log_8[\log_4(2x+1)] = \log_{27} 3$ for $x$?

Tags: logarithms

I'm stuck on this question.

> $$\log_8[\log_4(2x+1)] = \log_{27} 3$$

What I did was to manipulate the inner $\log_4$ to get $\log_8[\frac{\log_2(2x+1)}{\log_2 4}] = \frac{1}{3}$

Then manipulating the outer $\log_8$ to become $\frac{\log_2 8}{\log_2 2}$, I will get $2x+1 = 2^{\frac{4}{9}}$, which is not what the answer key wanted. For reference, answer key gives $x = 7\frac{1}{2}$.

Greatly appreciate any hint. Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

\begin{align}
\log_8[\log_4(2x+1)] &= \log_{27} 3\\
\log_8[\log_4(2x+1)] &= \frac{1}{3}\\
\log_4(2x+1) &= 8^\frac{1}{3}=2\\
2x+1&=4^2\\
x&=\frac{15}{2}
\end{align}